# Android: How to make navigation drawer opaque?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

How do I make Navigation drawer opaque. Currently i have made navigation drawer whenever i open the navigation drawer background text is also visible. How to overcome this situation.

Comment: post the layout of the drawer and how are you calling it

Comment: Try changing the background of your layout you have used for the navigation drawer to see the effect and even to find out where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the `android:background` property for your layout in the drawer content xml.
Add one if its absent.

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

or

```
android:background="@drawable/yourImageForBackground"
```

In the parent of your drawer content layout.

Eg.:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@android:color/black">
```

Comment: it didn't help. It is still transparent